# angular: select all checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an existing angular application and I am trying to add a 'select all' checkbox in the header of a table. I cant manage to make it work... My closest effort to success is this one, but it when clicked it checks all checkboxes even I have 1000 , despite that I have hardcoded a counter to check only the first 10 ones... And even though it checks all it submit the forms with only the first 10!! (it sends an email to selected accounts but this is working fine...). so here is my code:
html:

```html
 <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">  

                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="IsSelected"><!--SUP-1176 start-->
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="nowrap"><mat-checkbox style="left:-16px;" (change)="ToggleCheckAll()"></mat-checkbox>Επιλογή Κάρτας </th><!--SUP-1176 end-->
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
                                            <mat-checkbox [checked]="imchecked" class="example-margin" (change)="ToggleChecked(element)">
                                            </mat-checkbox>
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container> .....
```

and the javascript .ts code:

```ts
public ToggleCheckAll(){

    let i = 0;
    this.cards.forEach(c=>{ 
      if(i < 9){
        i++;
        this.imchecked = !this.imchecked; 
   
        this.ToggleChecked(c);
      }
      
    });
 
  }
//SUP-1176 end
  //changes selected status from object
  public ToggleChecked(c:CardModule.Card){


    if(c.IsSelected==null || c.IsSelected==undefined){
      c.IsSelected=false;
    }

    c.IsSelected=!c?.IsSelected;

    if(c?.IsSelected){ 
      this.selectedCards=[...this.selectedCards,c.Id.toString()];
    }
    else{
 
      var index:number=-1;

      for(var i=0;i<this.selectedCards.length;i++){
        if(c.Id.toString()==this.selectedCards[i]){
          index=i;
        }
      }

      if(index>-1){//console.log('4');
        this.selectedCards.splice(index,1);
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to select only the rows in the current page but it selects all... despite the pagination

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using the same variable `imchecked` for setting `checked` property in mat-checkbox.

Try using an array `imchecked: Array<boolean>` with size equal to the cards.length, and mark only the indices that you need checked on hitting `Select All`.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
 <mat-checkbox 
   [checked]="imchecked[i]"
   class="example-margin
   (change)="ToggleChecked(element)">
 </mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

Comment: so chaging this.imchecked = !this.imchecked; to this.imchecked[i] = !this.imchecked[i]; is fine in javascript?

Comment: yes, it is completely safe. Refer [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#populating_an_array) for more information.

Comment: by the way I get this js error when I add imchecked[i] main.js:23 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')
    at G (4760.js:1:3107)
    at Mf (main.js:23:158956)
    at md (main.js:23:157718)
    at hg (main.js:23:158145)
    at md (main.js:23:158171)
    at pg (main.js:23:165220)
    at Xm (main.js:23:158586)
    at md (main.js:23:158597)
    at hg (main.js:23:158145)

Comment: can you share a working example of your issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: its not easy its a very big application I will try

Comment: Here, check out the implementation on the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-z97tog?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)